# If Date in this range can be found in separate range, delete row

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, date-range

I have a Excel workbook, almost like a database, where I update Historical data each week. Using a separate sub, I pull in an Export as a worksheet to the book. I find the unique dates that are in the export. I then look at Historical data, and if the Historical date matches one of the Export dates, I delete the row in Historical. Eventually I copy and paste the Export in to the Historical data tab.

The code below works how I'd like it to, but I have some questions after the block of code:

```
Sub AddNewData()

'This will take what's in Export and put it in to Historical

Dim Historical As Worksheet
Dim Export As Worksheet
Dim exportdates As Range

Set Historical = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Historical")
Set Export = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")

'Pulling unique values of dates from this range and pasting to M1:
Export.Range("B2:B" & Export.Cells(Export.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Export.Range("M1"), Unique:=True

'Originally I was thinking I could make this a list of some sort vlookup or match?
'As of now, though, it goes unused...:
Set exportdates = Export.Range("M1:M" & Export.Cells(Export.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row)

For r = Historical.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Historical.Cells(r, 2).Value = exportdates(1, 1).Value Or _
        Historical.Cells(r, 2).Value = exportdates(2, 1).Value Or _
        Historical.Cells(r, 2).Value = exportdates(3, 1).Value _
        Then Historical.Rows(r).Delete
Next

'Copying and pasting Export data to Historical tab
Export.Range("A2:J" & Export.Cells(Export.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Historical.Range("A" & Historical.Cells(Historical.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

1) Can that IF statement be condensed somehow using the exportdates range?

2) This works just fine for a few hundred rows of data when my dates are simply the first of each month, but I also have an export that has each day as a date that I'll have to match with a different tab with daily information. That one has THOUSANDS of rows. I don't believe this macro will be much more efficient than simply sorting by date and eliminating myself? Can I change the IF statement to be more inclusive, like question 1?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have to delete many rows in Excel with VBA, the best practice is to assign these rows to a range and to delete the range at the end.

Thus, your code should be refactored in this part:

```
For r = Historical.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Historical.Cells(r, 2).Value = exportdates(1, 1).Value Or _
        Historical.Cells(r, 2).Value = exportdates(2, 1).Value Or _
        Historical.Cells(r, 2).Value = exportdates(3, 1).Value _
        Then Historical.Rows(r).Delete
Next
```

This is a simple sample that you can use for the refactoring (just make sure to write a few times `1` in `Range("A1:A20")` to see how it works:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim deleteRange As Range
    Dim cnt         As Long

    For cnt = 20 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(cnt, 1) = 1 Then
            If Not deleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, Cells(cnt, 1))
            Else
                Set deleteRange = Cells(cnt, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next cnt

    deleteRange.EntireRow.Select
    Stop
    deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Once you run the code it stops at the `Stop` sign. You see that the rows to be deleted are selected. Once you continue with <kbd>F5</kbd> they would be deleted. Consider removing the `Stop` and `.Select` line in your code.

Some general ideas how to speed up code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49514930/5448626

Comment: This works!
Instead of using:
   If Cells(cnt, 1) = 1 or Cells(cnt, 1) = 2 or Cells(cnt, 1) = 4 Then
Is there any way for me to say something like
   IF Cells(cnt, 1) = <one of the values in this set range>

In a simple line of code?

Comment: @yourleftleg  - congrats! :) If you have 3 conditions you need 3 conditions.

Comment: I actually ended up figuring out that I could essentially do 

iserror(Application.Match(CLng(.Cells(cnt, 2)), famedates, 0)) as the one line of code to check my exportdates range. That worked as well!

Comment: @yourleftleg - this is probably better, but thus you have to take care of a new variable - "famedates".