# Excel - slow VBA execution of simple loop

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I just want to make sure that text inside a column is changed into uppercase.

For this I am using the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("$G$6:$G$200")
    cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
Next cell

End Sub
```

In this case the loop runs over ~200 cells but it already takes about 15 seconds to execute. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use an array or turn off [screen updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089741/how-to-speed-up-vba-code/47092175#47092175), re-calculation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will copy the values into an array, do the ucase and write it back. In such a way you reduce the number of read and write accesses to the sheet which usually slows down the code as every write access might trigger events, recalculations or cause a screen updating.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    On Error GoTo EH
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("$G$6:$G$200")
    
    Dim vdat As Variant
    vdat = rg.Value
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(vdat, 1) To UBound(vdat, 1)
        For j = LBound(vdat, 2) To UBound(vdat, 2)
            vdat(i, j) = UCase(vdat(i, j))
        Next
    Next
    
    rg.Value = vdat

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Doing the operation using the array solved this. Just disabling screenupdate or events did not help much.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating between cells take times. Using an array and dropping the result at the end, iteration will be much faster and writing in each iteration makes the code slower. But `Evaluate` is more compact and has a similar efficiency:

```
  Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("$G$6:$G$200")
  rng.value = Evaluate("Upper(" & rng.Address & ")")
```

Comment: `Evaluate` has some quirks. In this example it will fail in case RC notation is turned on