# Loop optimization/Customization

Tags: excel, vba

The excel file I have is more than 1,000,000 rows and 26 columns.

Below is the code  which is used to find a particular data and a new file is created on the basis of that data and currently it is  taking around 15 mins to create a new file

Please if any expert can help me in processing the below macro faster.

```
Sub SplitSheetDataIntoMultipleWorkbooksBasedOnSpecificColumn()
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim nLastRow, nRow, nNextRow As Integer
    Dim strColumnValue As String
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim varColumnValues As Variant
    Dim varColumnValue As Variant
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
 
    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
   
    strColumnValue = "1021 VDDGC 104"
 
    If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
       objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
    End If
 
    varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys  
 
    For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
        varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)
 
        'Create a new Excel workbook
        Set objExcelWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add
        Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name
 
        objWorksheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy
        objSheet.Activate
        objSheet.Range("A1").Select
        objSheet.Paste
 
        For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
            If CStr(objWorksheet.Range("K" & nRow).Value) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then
               'Copy data with the same column "B" value to new workbook
               objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).EntireRow.Copy
  
               nNextRow = objSheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
               objSheet.Range("A" & nNextRow).Select
               objSheet.Paste
               objSheet.Columns("A:S").AutoFit
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Usually using [select and activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)  is not neccessary. And you can also try to turn off functionality in order to increase [speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089741/how-to-speed-up-vba-code/47092175#47092175)

Comment: We dealt with data like this and once we had the plan worked out we used SAS to do the analysis, not excel.

Comment: in addition to @Storax remarks, no need to Autofit after each Paste. Just once at the end will do.

Comment: Also: couldn't you use Autofilter and copy the filtered data at once ? Would be much faster

Answer (score 2):

### Copy Worksheet to a New Workbook

- Copies (exports) the worksheet to a new workbook.
- Sorts by and filters the criteria column.
- Deletes the filtered rows.

```vb
Sub SplitWorksheetData()

    Dim dt As Double: dt = Timer
    
    Const Criteria As String = "1021 VDDGC 104"
    Const CriteriaColumnIndex As Long = 2
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    If Not dict.Exists(Criteria) Then dict.Add Criteria, 1
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim Key As Variant

    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        
        sws.Copy
        Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData
         
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Dim ddrg As Range: Set ddrg = drg.Resize(drg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        
        drg.Sort drg.Columns(CriteriaColumnIndex), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
        drg.AutoFilter CriteriaColumnIndex, "<>" & Criteria
         
        Dim vrg As Range
        On Error Resume Next
            Set vrg = ddrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        dws.AutoFilterMode = False
        
        If Not vrg Is Nothing Then vrg.Delete
 
        ' Save code goes here...
        'dwb.SaveAs... 

    Next Key
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print Timer - dt

    MsgBox "Workbook created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```