# apache poi excel report from list of 1000 records taking more than 10 minutes

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have implemented a excel report in java using apache-poi library. In the end I have a list of objects with 1000 records. When I am traversing on those records and writing data in the report it is taking too much time I do not know if it is normal.

Below is what and all I have the working code:

Controller Class:

> please note that the list `report` has 1008 records, and finally when report is generated it took `10 minutes`

> When I debugged, the method `writeDataLines()` is taking this much time.

```
        List<PricingCalculationReport> report =  pricingRuleServiceImpl.applyPricingOnAirshopReport( pricingRequest, agentId );

        log.info( "logging pricing report: " );
        log.debug( objectMapper.writeValueAsString(report) );

        if( report != null ) {
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
            String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());

            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = "attachment; filename=PricingReport_" + currentDateTime + ".xlsx";
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

            PricingReporter excelExporter = new PricingReporter(report);

            excelExporter.export(response, new PricingCalculationReport());
        }
```

Report Class, export method:

```
public void export(HttpServletResponse response, PricingCalculationReport report) throws IOException {

    try {
        writeHeaderLine( "Pricing Report", report );
        writeDataLines();

        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();

        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Report Class, writeDataLines method:

```
private void writeDataLines() throws Exception {
    int rowCount = 2;

    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setFontHeight(10);
    style.setFont(font);

    for (PricingCalculationReport report : objects) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
        int columnCount = 0;

        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferId(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferItemId(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getRuleName(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getFareType().name(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getAdjustmentType().name(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getAdjustmentValue(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getIsVisible(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferItemBaseAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferItemTaxAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferItemTotalAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getNewOfferItemBaseAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getNewOfferItemTotalAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferBaseAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferTaxAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferTotalAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getNewOfferBaseAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getNewOfferTotalAmount(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferItemMarkupCalculated(), style);
        createCell(row, columnCount++, report.getOfferMarkupCalculated(), style);

    }
}
```

createCell method:

```
private void createCell(Row row, int columnCount, Object value, CellStyle style) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnCount);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
    if (value instanceof Integer) {
        cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Double) {
        cell.setCellValue((Double) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        cell.setCellValue((Boolean) value);
    } else if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
        cell.setCellValue( ((BigDecimal) value).doubleValue()  );
    } else {
        cell.setCellValue((String) value);
    }
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
}
```

Reporter class:

```
public class PricingReporter {

   private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
   private XSSFSheet sheet;
   private List<PricingCalculationReport> objects;

   public PricingReporter(List<PricingCalculationReport> objects) {
       this.objects = objects;
       workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   }
}
```

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: in `writeDataLines()` method, `objects` variable - where does it come from?

Comment: @AleksanderSzporka it is passed to the constructor while creating object of class `PricingReporter` . updated the question, please have a look at the bottom

Comment: @AleksanderSzporka in the first block of code please look for this line `PricingReporter excelExporter = new PricingReporter(report);`

Comment: Attach a profiler and find out where the time is really going?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose these methods write an open Excel sheet directly. PLease note that Excel takes reasonably much time when getting control, particularly when it comes to cell formatting or column sizing, and you pass control to Excel cca 20K times. However, bulk operations in Excel does not really take much more time. According to my experience in VBA the key is to reduce application-Excel swaps by applying an operation on a `Range` of cells (columns or rows or rectangles or even a noncontiguos `Union` of ranges).

So if you have 1008 rows of identical format then you can collect styles once from the first row, fill in the sheet with rough data, and apply formatting column by column at the end.

You can also consider turning off automated formatting services of Excel, see this [speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089741/how-to-speed-up-vba-code/47092175#47092175).

Comment: useful information. Are you able to suggest something specific to my code and what i tried ?

Comment: You apply the same `style` cell by cell, cca with `cell.setCellStyle(style)` 20K times. Excel supports bulk operation for applying style on a `Range`. Look for `Range` functions in your lib and apply the style at once like  `<range ref>.setCellStyle`, or there may be a `setRangeStyle` function, too.