# Loops works, but causes program to freeze

Tags: excel, vba

I have this small piece of code.

```
Sub FillRemainingDates()
    

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Set SearchRange = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(11)

    Dim cell As Range

    
    For Each cell In SearchRange
        
        If cell.Value = vbNullString And cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = cell.Offset(1, 9).Value Then
            cell = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
        End If

    Next
    

End Sub
```

Its goal is to attribute a value to a cell in a column depending on the value of a cell a row below:

The macro "works" in the sense that it does what I expect it to do, but whenever I run it it  causes the program to become unresponsive and freeze for a long time.

I think I'm missing something in the loop and it's causing the program to fall into an infinite loop or have to deal with more data than necessary.

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code that would obviously take a lot of time. How big is the used range? Perhaps in the column that you search in you are iterating below the used cells in that column. [How To Speed Up VBA Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47089741/4996248) might help.

Comment: @JohnColeman The range is around 5000 rows. I will try out the tips from that post, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array to work on - and then write that back to the sheet.

```vb
Sub FillRemainingDates()
    
    'ASSUMPTION: data start in column A
    
    '>>> change the names according to your project
    Const colNameOfColumn11 As Long = 11
    Const colNameOfColumn20 As Long = 20

    Dim arrSearch As Variant
    arrSearch = Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim varValue As Variant  '>>>> change type according to your values
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSearch, 1) - 1   ' don't check last row
        varValue = arrSearch(i, colNameOfColumn11)
        
        If varValue = vbNullString And _
            arrSearch(i, colNameOfColumn20) = arrSearch(i + 1, colNameOfColumn20) Then
            
            arrSearch(i, colNameOfColumn11) = arrSearch(i + 1, colNameOfColumn11)
        End If
    Next

    Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value = arrSearch

End Sub
```