# Excel VBA - Excessive Time to Complete

Tags: excel, vba

I created a simple spreadsheet with a bit of VBA code to hide/unhide based upon the color of the column header. If the column header is red, and I want it hidden, then I click the button "Hide". Alternatively, if I want those hidden columns to reappear, I click "Unhide". It works. Yay!

The actual task of unhiding/hiding works, the problem is that it takes entirely too long.

[snip of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAdVR.png)

Here's the code for hiding:

```
Sub HideColumnIfRed()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A:AT")

If c.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Here's the code for unhiding:

```
Sub HideColumnIfRed()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A:AT")

If c.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End If

Next c

End Sub
```

What can I do to optimize this task?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're looping over 46*1048576 cells. Only loop over the cells you actually care about.

Comment: Additionally to the previous hint you could turn off [Screenupdating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092175/6600940) etc.

Comment: How long is "too long"?

Comment: Look into [Used Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange)

Comment: I thought I had restricted the range to A:AT? Is this wrong?

Comment: Too long is about 5 minutes for only 10-15 columns in the range of A:AT.

Comment: I know zero about ScreenUpdating as this is my first time using VBA...but I'm looking at it. Thanks.

Comment: `? Range("A:AT").CountLarge` in Immediate pane gives `48234496` so yes that's a lot of cells to loop over

Answer (score 1):

As a quick (maybe dirty) fix you could intersect your columns you are after with the used range like that

```
For Each c In Intersect(Range("A:AT"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
```

But be careful as `ActiveSheet` might not always the sheet you expect it to be. On the other hand you already use `Range("A:AT")` without reference which already refers to `ActiveSheet` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I restricted the cells as suggested in @BigBen’s comment.

From this:

```
For Each c In Range("A:AT")
```

To this:

```
For Each c In Range("A2:AT2")
```

I then deleted the corresponding buttons, and recreated them. All works beautifully now.