# VBA code with private sub taking too long to process

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have 1903 lines of code that are incorporated in three function that works with Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal target As Range). They all works perfectly, but since it's 1903 lines, the process is too long. The first one goes like this :

```
If Target.Count = 1 Then
Dim Colr As Long, Txt As String

If Target.Address(0, 0) = "C9" Then
  Txt = "Please insert your purchase order number here"
End If

If Target.Address(0, 0) = "C53" Then
  Txt = "Please insert your purchase amount here"
End If

If Target.Address(0, 0) = "C97" Then
  Txt = "Please insert your purchase amount here"
End If
```

The second one goes like this :

```
If Target.Address = "$B$11" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Calculation sheet").Rows("9:15").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Sheets("Calculation sheet").Rows("9:15").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
  
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$B$11,$G$11")) Is Nothing Then

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annex 1").Rows(11).Hidden = _
      Len(Me.Range("$B$11").Value) = 0 Or Me.Range("$G$11").Value <> "Success"
      
End If

If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Calculation sheet").Rows("16:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Sheets("Calculation sheet").Rows("16:22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$B$12,$G$12")) Is Nothing Then

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annex1").Rows(12).Hidden = _
      Len(Me.Range("$B$12").Value) = 0 Or Me.Range("$G$12").Value <> "Success"
      
End If

If Target.Address = "$B$13" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Calculation sheet").Rows("23:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Sheets("Calculation sheet").Rows("23:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$B$13,$G$13")) Is Nothing Then

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annex1").Rows(13).Hidden = _
      Len(Me.Range("$B$13").Value) = 0 Or Me.Range("$G$13").Value <> "Success"
      
End If
```

The third one goes like this :

```
If Target.Address = "$C$9" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Annex1").Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Sheets("Annex1").Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If

If Target.Address = "$C$10" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
      Sheets("Annex1").Rows("10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
      Sheets("Annex1").Rows("10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If

If Target.Address = "$C$17" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Annex1").Rows("17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Sheets("Annex1").Rows("17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
```

Is there a way to make the process shorter or is there a solution ?

Comment: The first code is to get instructional text that dissapear and reappear when something is entered or erased. The second code is to get rows to showed in other sheets depending of something being entered in a row in this sheet and an option "success" to be selected in a drop-down list. The third one is the same but with other rows in another sheet.

Comment: Often times it's helpful to turn off application level features like screen updating and calcuations (and turning them back on at the end of the VBA). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092175/2221001) which covers the things that folks normally toggle off and then back on again and consider adding to the top and bottom of your very long code.

Comment: It still says that my process is too long. I've put before Application.Calculation = 
    xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False and after Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Comment: There are certain sets of rows in between each part, for the first one it's `9+X*44 = Target.Row`. For the second one, it's `X = Target.Row` with the Calculation Sheet part being `9+(X-11)*7 : 15+(X-11)*7`. For the third one you can put the rows you want to get adjusted ((un)hidden) in an array and then check if Target.Row is in said array.

Comment: Could you provide some context around what 'the process is too long means.  Is it the time taken to run the code, is it the number of lines of code.

Comment: I guess it's the number of lines. It says : when compiled, the code for a procedure can't exceed 64K.

Comment: If you have that many lines of code then likely you have a repeating pattern to your data/content, so a loop would be preferable to copy/pasting the same code over and over with small adjustments.

Comment: Are you using volatile function(s) at the front end? Like  NOW. TODAY. RANDBETWEEN. OFFSET. INDIRECT. INFO (depending on its arguments), CELL (depending on its arguments), SUMIF (depending on its arguments)? "A Volatile Function is one that causes recalculation of the formula in the cell where it resides every time Excel recalculates. This occurs regardless of whether the precedent data and formulas on which the formula depends have changed, or whether the formula also contains non-volatile functions." -> see on WWW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be what you're aiming for - look at the repeated parts of your code and figure out how to only write each part one time...

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only handling one-cell changes
    
    DoMessage Target
    HideShowRows Target
    Part3 Target
    
End Sub


Sub DoMessage(Target As Range)
    Dim txt As String
    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
        Case "C9": txt = "Please insert your purchase order number here"
        Case "C53", "C97": txt = "Please insert your purchase amount here"
    End Select
    If Len(txt) > 0 Then
        'show message
    End If
End Sub


Sub HideShowRows(Target As Range)
    Const ROWS_PER_BLOCK As Long = 7
    Dim rwNum As Long, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    'Adjust B11:B50 to cover all rows of interest
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B11:B50")) Is Nothing Then
        rwNum = 9 + ((Target.Row - 11) * ROWS_PER_BLOCK) 'start row of block to hide/show
        wb.Sheets("Calculation sheet").Cells(rwNum, "A"). _
             Resize(ROWS_PER_BLOCK).EntireRow.Hidden = (Len(Target.Value) = 0)
    End If
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B11:B50,G11:G50")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target.EntireRow
            wb.Worksheets("Annex 1").rows(Target.Row).Hidden = _
                Len(.Columns("B").Value) = 0 Or .Columns("G").Value <> "Success"
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub Part3(Target As Range)
    Dim rw As Long
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        rw = Target.Row
        Select Case rw
            'add more rows as needed
            Case 9, 10, 17
                Sheets("Annex1").rows(rw).EntireRow.Hidden = _
                    Len(Target.Value) = 0
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Added "Part3"...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the process shorter

The crux of your issue is that you're running a bunch of `If` statements comparind values when you don't need to.  So, yes, make things shorter by not comparing items when you don't need to.

For your first block of code, you have many `If` statements in the same format.  Instead of running the same `If` statement many times, we can use one `If` statement in a `For Each` loop, and then exit from the loop once we've found a match.  The `Exit For` will stop comparing after it's been reached, so that will cut down on run time.  All you need to do is update the `specialCells` collection.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim specialCells As New Collection
    specialCells.Add ("C9")
    specialCells.Add ("C53")
    
    Dim specialCell As Variant
    For Each specialCell In specialCells
        
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = specialCell Then
            Debug.Print "Selected"
            Exit For
        End If
    
    Next specialCell

End Sub
```

The second block of code you've shown might be fixed in a similar manner, but it's hard to saw based on how it's presented.

For the thrid block of code, a similar approach.  Leverage the fact that you're performing the same action by using a `For Each` loop, and exitting once you've found your cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Exit early if the column isn't "C"
    If Target.Column <> 3 Then GoTo ExitEarly

    Dim rows As New Collection
    rows.Add 9
    rows.Add 10
    rows.Add 17

    Dim row As Variant
    For Each row In rows

        If row = Target.row Then
    
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Sheets("Annex1").rows(row).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                Sheets("Annex1").rows(row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
            
            Exit For
        
        End If
    
    Next row
    
ExitEarly:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten the number of lines you need to be able to contract repeating structures into looping structures.

Part 1

You have many  address vs text.  This is a classic recipe for using a dictionary.  The dictionary can be compiled in advance of your loop in a separate function

Based on the very limited data in your question and using the fact that a collection can act as a dictionary if the keys are strings.

```
Public Function CompileAddressDict() as Collection
    Dim myC as collection
    Set myC = new Collection
    With myC
        .Add Key:="C9", Item:="Please insert your purchase order number here"
        .Add Key:="C53" , Item:= "Please insert your purchase amount here"
        .Add Key:="C97" , Item:= "Please insert your purchase amount here"
        ' etc etc
    end with

    set CompileAddressDict= myC

End Function
```

As part of your code initialisation you would call CompileAddressDict
e.g. at the module level

```
Dim myAddrDict as Collection
```

Then in the initialisation sub

```
Set myAddrDict = CompileAddressDict
```

Then you can condense all the code you present in part 1 to  the single line below

```
    myTxt = myAddrDict.Item(Target.Address(0, 0))
```

Similar techniques can be used for the other two parts you show.