# String function does not work correctly using Worksheet_Change(event) , But works correctly as user defined Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a function to concatenate cells with delimiter `”,”`. 
When I use it as a formula on excel, then it outputs correct result, 
**But**, when I use it by `Worksheet_Change(event)`, then the result is strange and format of output cell is changed to number. 
If I later changed format of output cell to **General**, this did not solve the problem. 
[image]

This my function of concatenation:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Function ConcRange(rng As Range, Optional Delim As String = ",") As String
     
    Dim cel As Range
     
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Trim(cel.Value) <> "" Then
           ConcRange = ConcRange & Delim & CStr(Trim(cel.Value))
        End If
    Next cel
     
   If Len(ConcRange) > 0 Then
     ConcRange = Right(ConcRange, Len(ConcRange) - 1)   'to remove "," at far left
   End If
     
End Function
```

And this the sheet event code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
  
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  
    Const ResultCel As String = "C2"
   
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Me.Range("A1:A50")
   
    Me.Range(ResultCel).Value = ConcRange(rng)
     
   Application.EnableEvents = True
    
  End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Set cell wrap text to true one the one with `####`   All those hash symbols just mean the content is too wide to display....

Comment: @Tim Williams ,the result cell is already set to Wrap text.

Comment: Your code should previously format the respective cell as text. Otherwise, Excel guesses and see it as a huge number, formatting as Scientific, I think,

Comment: @FaneDuru , your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Decimal-Delimiter-Separated String Converted to Number Issue

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const RESULT_CELL As String = "C2"

    Dim rng As Range, LastRow
    
    ' Check for intersection.
    With Me.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        Set rng = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no intersection
    
    ' Reference the range.
    LastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow < rng.Row Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Set rng = rng.Resize(LastRow - rng.Row + 1)
    
    ' Reference the resulting cell.
    Dim rCell As Range: Set rCell = Me.Range(RESULT_CELL)
    
    ' Either write a formula...
    With rCell
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Formula = "=""" & ConcRange(rng) & """"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
    
    ' ... or change the number format.
'    With rCell
'        .NumberFormat = "@"
'        Application.EnableEvents = False
'            .Value = ConcRange(rng) ' not with formula!
'        Application.EnableEvents = True
'        '.NumberFormat = "General" ' optional!?
'        ' Remove the green arrow for 'Number stored as text' (not recommended!).
'        'Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False
'        ' Note that this is an Application property i.e. all 'NumberAsText' errors
'        ' will be ignored until you set it back to 'True' programmatically
'        ' or in 'Excel->Options->Formulas->Error checking rules>Numbers...'
'    End With

End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1` or `B_ConcRange_Function` (used by OP)**

```vb
Function ConcRange(rng As Range, Optional Delim As String = ",") As String
     
    Dim cel As Range, CellString As String, Result As String
     
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        CellString = Trim(CStr(cel.Value))
        If Len(CellString) > 0 Then
            Result = Result & Delim & CellString
        End If
    Next cel
     
    ' Remove leading delimiter.
    If Len(Result) > 0 Then
        ConcRange = Right(Result, Len(Result) - Len(Delim))
    End If
     
End Function
```

Comment: I have chose your answer because it is more versatile 

Answer (score 2):

The cell is being set to a number format ... force it to text format by adding the line

```
Me.Range(ResultCel).NumberFormat = "@"
```

before the line

```
Me.Range(ResultCel).Value = ConcRange(rng)
```

Comment: On the result cell I got this error (The Number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe) , Sure I can choose `Ignore error` to bypass this error. Is there a way to do it using VBA

Comment: To actually ignore an error in code, you would precede the line(s) with `On Error Resume Next` and follow the line(s) with `On Error Goto 0` ... but that it literally just ignoring the error not resolving the underlying problem. See if that works for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708312/how-can-i-use-vba-to-ignore-green-triangle-error-in-range-without-looping-cell-b