# Forcing Excel to treat a number as a string

Tags: c++, excel, qt

I filled an Excel table via QXlsx (available on GitHub) with numbers that should in any case be treated as strings. In Excel the affected cells show a green triangle which says that the content is actually a number.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

In Excel I found an option which suppresses the warnings. But I am searching for a solution within QXlsx. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Seems better asked on that project's own repository/issue tracker.

Comment: How do you write your numbers into the Excel document?

Comment: In QXlsx there is the method:
bool write(int row, int col, const QVariant &value, const Format &format=Format());

Comment: @MegaPit, I see, but how do you use that function in your code?

Comment: There is nothing special to say. I have two methods AddColumn and AddValue which create one after another the table.

Comment: Try converting `value` to an alphanumeric variable.

Comment: That is a **feature** of Excel. Unless `Qxlsx` has a method for suppressing that warning in the Excel application, I don't think you'll be able to.

Comment: Seems you already asked with the maintainer:(https://github.com/QtExcel/QXlsx/issues/87), but it also seems he is busy, there are a lot of items having status 'help wanted'

Comment: @MegaPit: Here's the relevant documentation: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fix-text-formatted-numbers-by-applying-a-number-format-6599c03a-954d-4d83-b78a-23af2c8845d0. You can turn it off: File > Options > Formulas > Error checking rules > Unheck "Numbers formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe" > OK.

Comment: @Azeem: Thanks for your help! But I try to solve the problem programmaticaly with QXlsx which is an Excel library for Qt/C++

Comment: @MegaPit: Sure, no problem! I've looked at it. Reproduced your scenario with a sample program and then figured out that the library has nothing to do with it. It just reads/writes/manipulates in that specific format. It doesn't control MS Excel. MS Excel generates those warnings and you can either turn those off or just let them be.

Comment: This is how to ignore the error using VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317555/ignore-number-stored-as-text-error-in-excel-programmatically-using-vba